# document.getElementById('myid').value is not working when input type is number

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, codeigniter

I am doing a project in codeigniter and ajax.
my view page

```
<input type="number" id="quantityavailable" name="availableqty" required="required">
```

Ajax code

```
<script> 
function getquantity(id)
    {
        //alert('this id value :'+id);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>material_issue/get_quantity/'+id,
            data: { id:id }, 
            success: function(data){
               //alert(data);
            document.getElementById('quantityavailable').value=data;
        },
         });
    }
</script>
```

Controller

```
public function get_quantity($id)
    {      
                    //print_r($id);exit();
                     $this->db->where("g_id", $id);
                     $query = $this->db->get('goods');
                     $val = $query->result_array();
                     echo $val[0]['g_qty'];

    }
```

My issue is When alert data I am getting the right result. but the result is not displaying in the field. 
When I changed input `type="number"` input `type="text"` the result is displaying in the right field.

Comment: Is `typeof data === 'number'` ?

Comment: Try this `document.getElementById('quantityavailable').value=parseInt(data);`

Comment: @JYoThI its working thangs

Comment: What I have noticed is that document.getElementById('quantityavailable').value will get the value if an actual number was entered but if other characters were entered it does not get the value.